# Problem with Paging 404

Tags: pagination, rewrite-rules

On my Wordpress site, house is a page with short code written in it to paginate a get terms loop.

Currently below urls works perfectly to return 2nd page of the loop

```
/house/?paged=2    
/index.php?pagename=house&paged=2
```

Then I added the below

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
add_rewrite_rule('^house/page/([0-9]+)/?$', 'index.php?pagename=house&paged=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic', 10, 0);
```

However /house/page/2/ still returns 404 not found.

Comment: Did you flush the rewrite rules? Settings -> Permalinks -> Save Changes without any changes. If so, another great debugging step for this kind of thing is to get the plugin wp query monitor, which will show a breakdown of all the rewrite rules WordPress considered in returning the page. You can verify your rule is showing up there at all.

Comment: @tmdesigned you are right, I did not flush the rewrite rules by going to settings and  resave permalinks. Now it is working. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

As answer provided by @tmdesigned in comments above.

An extra step is needed, to go to settings and resave permalinks.